# Why does quantum entanglement break?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Why does quantum entanglement break when the corresponding particles are intefered with? Is there possibly any way to actualy use it, such as in interstellar communication?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately quantum entanglement does not convey information faster than light, despite some scientific-sounding claims to the contrary.  Entanglement is kind of like two sealed boxes guaranteed to contain identical objects.  I can't know what is in either box until I open mine, nor can you until you open yours-- but we know in advance that what I find in mine will match what you find in yours.  The QM "magic" is in the fact that (due to the uncertainty principle) Nature herself doesn't know what's in the QM boxes until they are opened.

The entanglement between particles does not "break" when the corresponding particles encounter other particles (that is, when they are interfered with).  Instead, the entanglement is spread to the other particles and essentially diluted.  Entanglement is a form of quantum information, and there's a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hiding_theorem) to the effect that quantum information cannot be created or destroyed-- but it can be spread out enough that it's very difficult to find and sort out.